# I have to modify the block to use a cursor to read and display the information for the saved baskets of shopper 26 in my database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
lv_basket_num NUMBER (3);
lv_created_date DATE;
lv_qty_num NUMBER(2);
lv_sub_num NUMBER(5,2);
lv_days_num NUMBER(3);
lv_shopper_num NUMBER(3) := 26;

BEGIN
SELECT idBasket, dtcreated, quantity, subtotal
INTO lv_basket_num, lv_created_date, lv_qty_num, lv_sub_num
FROM BB_BASKET
WHERE idShopper = lv_shopper_num
AND orderplaced= 0;

lv_days_num := SYSDATE-lv_created_date;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_basket_num||'*'||lv_created_date||'*'||lv_qty_num||'*'||lv_sub_num||'*'||lv_days_num);

END;
```

Comment: What is your question? WHat have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: the above is the code in which I have to modify that block to use a cursor to read and display information for saved baskets of shopper 26

Comment: But what have you tried to achieve that, and what problem do you have with your modified code? Showing us code that presumably works (but throws too-many-rows?) doesn't explain what help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to "convert" that `SELECT` into a cursor:

```
cursor cur_r is select ... <your query goes here>;
```

Then you have to declare a cursor variable (which will hold the result returned by the cursor) (instead bunch of variables you declared now), open the cursor, fetch from it, take care about exiting the loop, close the cursor. Way too many actions, so - why wouldn't you let Oracle do that for you? Switch to a cursor `FOR` loop.

Here's how:

```
DECLARE
  lv_shopper_num NUMBER(3) := 26;
BEGIN
  for cur_r in (SELECT idBasket, dtcreated, quantity, subtotal,
                       sysdate - dtcreated as lv_days_num
                FROM BB_BASKET
                WHERE idShopper = lv_shopper_num
                  AND orderplaced = 0
               )
  loop               
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur_r.idBasket ||'*'|| cur_r.dtcreated ||'*'|| 
                         cur_r.quantity ||'*'|| cur_r.subtotal  ||'*'|| lv_days_num);
  end loop;
END;
```